# How to pass USER ID from template to function to get values in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

i want to pass my user id to service when i click on edit.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let visit of visits" style="border-top: 1px solid black">
          <td>{{ visit?.ID }}</td>
          <td>{{ visit?.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ visit?.height }}</td>
            <td>{{ visit?.weight }}</td>
            <td>{{ visit?.patientnote }}</td>
            <td>{{ visit?.doctornote }}</td>
            <td>{{ visit?.nursenote }}</td>
            <td><button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="edit()">EDIT</button></td>
            <td><button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="delete()">DEL</button></td>
```

[image]

Comment: if its not visit id and than let me know where you have userid ...i dont see in you code right now..have you stored it some where

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Comment: Thank you for reply pranay am getting id  but
how to pass that id in URL .

http://localhost:8080/api/id

Comment: Hi updated my answer , you need to use routing for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use Angular Routing if you want to pass value in url, something as below

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Component} from '../Module/Component';
import {ListComponent} from "../Module/ListComponent";

export const ApplicationRoutes = [
{ path: 'Rpt/:id', component: Component },//allows to pass id in route
{ path: 'RptList', component: ListComponent },
{ path: '', component:ListComponent }
];
```

if not aware about routing you can check rounting : https://angular.io/guide/router

below will work

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" 
     (click)="edit(visit?.ID)">EDIT</button>
```

in ts file function needs to take argument, you can make arugment optional also

```
edit(id?:any)
{}
```

Comment: when i click on edit button need to redirect another component with this is id
please suggest the best approach.

Comment: @Narendar - for navigation from code make use of   this.router.navigate(['/heroes',, hero.id]);

Comment: following  this.router.navigate(['edit',this.idparam]);but  how to use this id in next component's typescript

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass id as being parameter of the function:

```
<td><button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="edit(visit.ID)">EDIT</button></td>
```